# How to Grab a Viewcontroller in AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, storyboard, viewcontroller

I was going throw a To Do app tutorial and everything went well until i faced a difficulty because the tutorial wanted me to grab a viewcontroller through the AppDelegate.

To explain it better i started a personal project for fun where i wanted to add some different tools in one app.

So, i stated by creating a TabBarController as my first viewcontroller. so, i can separate each tool on a different ViewController and access it through the TabBar.

While the ToDo app tutorial only had one NavigationBarController as its main rootViewController, there i lost it because i cannot grab the desired ViewController like the tutorial did.

Below i provide the Delegate Code the Tutorial had with the StoryBoard i am using. so, you can see what i try to access.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHCuh.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3YbW.jpg

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //initialize TaskStore
        let taskStore = TaskStore()

        let todoTasks = [Task(name: "Meditate"), Task(name: "Banana")]
        let doneTasks = [Task(name: "Netflix")]

        taskStore.tasks = [todoTasks, doneTasks]

        //Grab the Tasks Controller
        let tasks = window?.rootViewController?.children.first as? Tasks

        //Set the taskstore accordingly
        tasks?.taskStore = taskStore

        return true
    }
```

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: It's pointless to create data in AppDelegate and hand it over to a view controller. Move the entire body of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` except the last line into `viewDidLoad` of the view controller

Answer (score 0):

Your rootViewController is UITabBarController and it takes UIViewController as it's subviews (children).

You have added UINavigationBarController(which is subclass of VC). So code you have will give you NavController not the Tasks. You will need to get children of the NavController to get Tasks.

```
if let navController = window?.rootViewController?.children.first ? UINavigationController {
    let tasks = navController?.children.first ? Tasks 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you you explained it really well and it worked!